# Determine if current time is within an array of time ranges

Tags: javascript

For a website blocking/productivity app written in javascript, I'd like to have a user input a series of time ranges available for free time (in his local time). Example:

06:00-06:30

12:30-13:00

23:45-00:15

24 format is not required (I'm just assuming it will be easier)

The program should then check the specified free time ranges against the current time to determine whether block mode is on or off.

My rough idea is to use an inbuilt Javascript function to grab the current DateTime, and convert it to 24 hour format if necessary. I think the time ranges will be in an array. I'm not sure how to check if the current date is within a range in the array.

The logic must also be able to handle the crossover from 23:00 to 0:00.

Anyways that is my line of thought. Thanks for any suggestions including ones that take a different path.

Comment: It would be much easier if the ranges were in a single unit like minutes (e.g. 06:00-0630 would be 360-390) or seconds. What have you tried? As it is now, this question is too broad. You're asking someone to write all the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyways that is my line of thought. Thanks for any suggestions including ones that take a different path.

If you want to check if *current* time is in range then the *range* should be DATE + TIME as current time is DATE + TIME

## Possible solution

You can convert all three datetimes to moment instances and just use

```
start.isBefore(current)
&& current.isBefore(end)
```

Moment docs on `isBefore` and `isAfter` : https://momentjs.com/

Comment: This isn't really an answer. The "possible solution" can be done with plain Date objects using `<` and `>`, but the OP wants time only.

Answer (score 0):

> **"I'm not sure how to check if the current date is within a range in the array."**

You'd loop through the array and compare. I'd suggest storing the ranges as an array of objects where each individual range is something like `{start: "10:15", end: "10:45"}`.

JavaScript doesn't have time objects, only `Date` that includes date and time information. So I think it would be easiest to convert the current time to the "hh:mm" format as a string and then just do simple string compares against your range values, rather than worrying about converting the range values to date objects. So:

```
var timeRanges = [
  { start: "06:00", stop: "06:30" },
  { start: "12:30", stop: "13:00" },
  { start: "23:45", stop: "00:15" }
]

function isTimeInRange(time) {
  for (var i = 0; i < timeRanges.length; i++) {
    var range = timeRanges[i]
    if ((time > range.start && time < range.stop)
      || (range.start > range.stop && (time > range.start || time < range.stop))) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

But you can make the code neater, and shorter, using the [array `.some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=control), with or without [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
var timeRanges = [
  { start: "06:00", stop: "06:30" },
  { start: "12:30", stop: "13:00" },
  { start: "23:45", stop: "00:15" }
]

function isTimeInRange(time) {
  return timeRanges.some(range =>
    (time > range.start && time < range.stop)
    || (range.start > range.stop && (time > range.start || time < range.stop))
  )
}

function pad(d) {
  return ("0" + d).slice(-2)
}

function getCurrentTime() {
  var now = new Date()
  return pad(now.getHours()) + ":" + pad(now.getMinutes())
}

console.log("Current time in range? " + isTimeInRange(getCurrentTime()))
// test some other times
console.log(isTimeInRange("06:15")) // true
console.log(isTimeInRange("12:35")) // true
console.log(isTimeInRange("13:30")) // false
console.log(isTimeInRange("23:50")) // true
console.log(isTimeInRange("00:14")) // true
```

Obviously you can change `<` and `>` to `<=` and `>=` if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```js
start = "10:10";
end = "16:30";
function isInRange(start, end, current){
  start = convertTimeToMinute(start);
  end = convertTimeToMinute(end);
  current = convertTimeToMinute(current);
  return start <= current && current <= end;
}
function convertTimeToMinute(time){
  return +time.slice(0,1)*60 + +time.slice(3,4);
}

console.log(isInRange(start,end, "15:20"));
console.log(isInRange(start,end, "20:20"));
```

Comment: `+time.slice(0,1)*60 + time.slice(3,4)` should be `time.slice(0,2)*60 + +time.slice(3);` since `*60` will convert the first string to number but the second slice will make it a string again. ;-) As posted, `convertTimeToMinute('20:20'))` returns `1202` instead of `1220`.

Comment: Oops. My bad. Thank @RobG